# Multiple Images in Header Div

Tags: html, css

I am looking to have the logo aligned in the center and social media buttons aligned on the right in the header. How do I achieve? I've been able to get it aligned with my nav bar but that's not what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

<header>
<div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cosDXx1.png"/></a>
</div>
<div class ="social">
    <a href="http://instagram.com/phipsibing"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1GhbSOj.png"/></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/phi_psi_bing"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/oawoJtC.png"/></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/phipsi.sociallist?fref=ts"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2dAtAX3.png"/></a>
</div>

</header> 

<nav>
    <ul class="egmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="has-sub">About</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brothers</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="has-sub">Philanthropy</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Kovacs Color Run</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Greek God</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Boys & Girls Club</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header {
    height:105px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}

header img{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header .social a {
    float:right;
}


ul.egmenu {  
    background: #333; 
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.egmenu > li {  
    position: relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}

ul.egmenu ul {
    background: #444; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 100%;
}

ul.egmenu a { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    color: white; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    padding: 0 20px; 
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.egmenu li { 
    list-style: none;
}

ul.egmenu li:hover { 
    background: #555;  
}
ul.egmenu li:hover ul { 
    display: block;
    padding:0;  
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.egmenu {  height: auto; padding:0;}
    ul.egmenu > li {  float: none; width: 100%; }
    ul.egmenu a { line-height: 40px; }
    ul.egmenu ul { position: relative; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 601px) {
    ul.egmenu li:hover { background: #555;  }
    ul.egmenu li:hover ul { display: block;  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.egmenu {  height: auto; }
    ul.egmenu > li {  float: none; width: 100%; }
    ul.egmenu a { line-height: 40px; }
    ul.egmenu ul { position: relative; }

    ul.egmenu li.tap { background: #555;  }
    ul.egmenu li.tap ul { display: block;  }
}
```

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcxa341s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `logo` div and use `CSS` to add a background for the header.

Change to this:

```
header {
    height:105px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/cosDXx1.png') no-repeat center;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And use `margin-top` for the `social` div to adjust the positioning.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcxa341s/2/)**

## **UPDATE**

Change:

```
header .social a {
    float:right;
}
```

To this:

```
header .social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcxa341s/5/)

Comment: The positioning is correct for the first demo but I need the logo to be a clickable image (goes back to homepage)

Comment: @LeonardLabita check update :) Adjust according to your needs

Comment: Done. Sorry to bother but I have just one more question. I need the social media buttons to be spaced out a bit more. What css would I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the logo a background for the header and get rid of the logo `div`. Then your social         media icons will align without a problem.
2. Use `position:absolute` for social media.

   .social {
   position: absolute;
   right: 20px;
   top: 50px;
   }

Comment: The positioning is right with this technique but I need the logo to be a clickable link (to the home page)

Comment: Then you could use `position:absolute` for the social media. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header {
    height:105px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}
header .logo{ margin: 0 auto;}
header .social{margin-top:-24px;}
header img{
    display:inline-block;

}

header .social a {
    float:right;
}


ul.egmenu {  
    background: #333; 
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.egmenu > li {  
    position: relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}

ul.egmenu ul {
    background: #444; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 100%;
}

ul.egmenu a { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    color: white; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    padding: 0 20px; 
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.egmenu li { 
    list-style: none;
}

ul.egmenu li:hover { 
    background: #555;  
}
ul.egmenu li:hover ul { 
    display: block;
    padding:0;  
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.egmenu {  height: auto; padding:0;}
    ul.egmenu > li {  float: none; width: 100%; }
    ul.egmenu a { line-height: 40px; }
    ul.egmenu ul { position: relative; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 601px) {
    ul.egmenu li:hover { background: #555;  }
    ul.egmenu li:hover ul { display: block;  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.egmenu {  height: auto; }
    ul.egmenu > li {  float: none; width: 100%; }
    ul.egmenu a { line-height: 40px; }
    ul.egmenu ul { position: relative; }

    ul.egmenu li.tap { background: #555;  }
    ul.egmenu li.tap ul { display: block;  }
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcxa341s/4/)